# function as parameter vs function pointer as parameter

Tags: c++, c, function, parameters

While listening through Stanford's [Programming Abstractions](http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=11f4f422-5670-4b4c-889c-008262e09e4e) course, I come across some piece of code that looks like the following.

```
void plot(double start, double end, double (fn)(double)) {
    double i;
    for (i = start; i <= end; i += 1)
        printf("fn(%f) = %f\n", i, fn(i));
}

double plus1(double x) {
    return x + 1;
}

int main(void) {
    plot(1, 10, plus1);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the code on my system using GCC, then G++; they both run perfectly.

I know that passing an `int i = 2` into a function such as `void func1(int a)` will make a new copy of that `i` for that function while passing `&i` to `void func2(int *a)` will only give the function `func2` the address of `i`.

So can anyone explain to me what is the mechanism for passing `fn` to `plot` and how it differs from passing a function pointer as parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between `void foo(double fn(double))` and `void foo(double (*fn)(double))`. Both declare functions which take a pointer to a function as a parameter.

This is similar to how there is no difference between `void bar(double arr[10])` and `void bar(double* arr)`.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your second claim concerning arrays? Especially when it's C++?

Comment: There is a bit difference, in former, `fn` is implcitly a pointer to function , and in the latter `fn` is explicitly declared pointer to function

Comment: @user946850: `§8.3.5/5`: ... After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or “function returning T” is adjusted to be “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T,” respectively. ...

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: You can choose to think of it that way, but there is no way of detecting the difference, so I don't see how it is a relevant point.

Comment: You can see easily that the compiler evaluates a[x] to *(a + x) anyway. If you write `char *s = "Hello";` and use `s[3]` or `3[s]` it will work exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my mistake.

```
void foo(int (fn)(int)){}
void bar(int (*fn)(int)){}
```

compile above code like this:

> gcc -S sample.c

you will find that there's no difference.
just different coding style.

you may try to compile and run this code as well:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(int (fn)(int))
{
    printf("foo: %x.\n",fn);
}
void bar(int (*fn)(int))
{
    printf("bar: %x.\n",fn);
}
int main(int argc)
{
    foo(main);
    bar(main);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read my question again. I asked for the difference between a function pointer in a parameter list vs a function prototype in a parameter list.

Comment: my fault.I wrote a new answer.